# Making sense of syntax

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Hello I'm trying to write a script with two input arguments, number of steps as first and directory as a second. Script should enter the chosen directory and do one of these steps by random:

1) create new directory with a random name of 5 characters
2) enter the home or first existing subdirectory

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $2

for ((c=1; c<=$1; c++))
do
n2=`expr $RANDOM % 2`
n3=`expr $RANDOM % 2`

if [ $n2 -eq 0 ];then
     name=$(tr -dc "[:alpha:]" < /dev/urandom | head -c 5)
     mkdir $name
else
   if[ $n3 -eq 0 ];then
     cd $1
   else
     first=$(ls -d */)
     cd $first
   fi
fi
done
```

When I execute the script I get an error: "line 13: syntax error near unexpected token 'then'"
Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: `[` is a command, as such it needs spaces around it so `if[` is invalid. Use `if [`.

Comment: Use `$(( $RANDOM % 2))` for arithmetic, not `expr`.

Comment: Make things easier for yourself and install/use [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/). It automatically points out this and other problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the space before the opening `[` on your second if.

```
if [ $n3 -eq 0 ];then
```

Should work.

The reason why `[` must be enclosed by brackets is, that `[` is an command, not some bash-built-in special syntax. It happens to be a built-in command, but it still obeys the same syntax rules as any other command.

Comment: It still needs the space. ANd builtin or not, it's still a command, not a syntax element.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: There's nothing particularly unfortunate about `[` being a shell built-in. The point is that it behaves *syntactically* like a command, not like special syntax. If you write `if[`, the shell looks for a command named `if[`. On the other hand, `;` is special syntax and doesn't require whitespace around it.

Comment: gniourf_gniourf happy `:)`